# Controlling the number of concurrent sessions for a single user

Tags: java, spring, session, authentication, spring-security

I've been reading [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session) on how to control the number of concurrent sessions for one single user. This is what I've got so far:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception
    {
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry authorizeRequests = http.authorizeRequests();

        authorizeRequests.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**").permitAll();
        authorizeRequests.antMatchers("/logon").permitAll();
        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

        http.httpBasic();

        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher()
    {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

And in order to test it, I open two browsers (FireFox and Chrome) and try to log them in one after another. I expect once the second one logs in, the first one not to be able to use the services anymore. But the first one is still logged in and its session ID is still valid. Can someone help me find my problem?

Comment: Becuase I don't want Spring to create my session (namely when the user authenticates using Http Basic Authentication). I'll create the session in my `/logon` API manually. In other words, I do use sessions but only if I authentication them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. I have APIs that need either a valid session ID or the Http Basic Authentication to work. And I'm calling them with session ID right now. I'm expecting the first browser's session ID to be invalid after the second one logs in. But still, after the second one authenticates, the first one's able to use the server.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure of that. I've been chasing that ghost before so I know what you are talking about. And I can definitely confirm that my requests are getting through because of the session ID they carry.

Comment: @dur Affirmative. But let me correct you a little. The second request should destroy the first session. And when the third request comes in, there's no matching session with the ID it carries.

Comment: To me, the "log out" is a request asking the server to destroy some session, providing the session ID to be destroyed. Having said that, the third request plays no role. And I've got some reasons to believe so. Session being destroyed is an action which based on you can do stuff (freeing resources and making a log or whatever). This action should happen with the second request coming in. Otherwise, the third request may never come in which means the action will never happen and this means that now you have two sessions for one user. Paradox. Nevertheless, this is not what the q is asking about